# Designing Database for Role Based Access Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design

I am trying to build a MVC Core app for an organisation. There is some vague requirements which I am not able to comprehend. I hope the community helps me out here.

There will be two types of users. One will be the admin and the other will be the normal users. The admin can access the admin module and the rest of the modules while each of these normal users will have access to different modules (except the admin one) and the sub-menus inside those modules. Let me explain that.

Let us suppose we have two modules : Disaster Recovery and Asset Tracking. The admin will be able to access each of these modules. But some of the normal users may or may not be able to access each of these two modules. Some of the users may have the authorization to access both modules while some of them will have access to only one.

Now here comes the tricky part. Inside each modules are sub-menus. For example if we have a module named Asset Tracking, the sub-menus inside this module can be ASST0001, ASST0002 and so on. These sub-menus are my MVC views. Again if a user has access to a module does not mean he/she will have access to the whole sub-menus of that said module. This app will be scalable and the no of users may increase as the time progresses.

How do I approach this problem? What would be the most efficient way and scalable way to approach this problem ?

I am sorry if I may seem naive but this is my first real job at designing something like this. I search the internet and most of them were talking about Roles, Users and Permissions which honestly just breezed over my head. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom requirements for this [Creating a custom requirement](https://andrewlock.net/custom-authorisation-policies-and-requirements-in-asp-net-core/#creating-a-custom-requirement) is a blog post for this.

You can even inject Dbcontext or repositories in requirement handle